# Design Method for iPad App

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface

I am working on the initial stages of an app and would like to employ the design implemented in lynda.com’s app for iPad. My question is what design patterns are they using to create the Playlist table on the left hand side which flies in from the left when the scene appears? I’m guessing it’s a view with a tableview that is added as a subview to main screen. The reason I’m trying to use something like this is to move away from the SplitView paradigm so I can have more screen real-estate for the right hand side of the screen. See screen shot below.

[image: Screen Shot from Lynda.com App]

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't received any feedback on this question so I'm wondering if I need to provide more info etc.?